# How to add new list item to unordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I have an HTML page with an unordered list like the following (simplified):

```
<ul id="myList">
    <li id="item1">Item 1 <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="myButton">Add</a></li>
    <li id="item2">Item 2 <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="myButton">Add</a></li>
    <li id="item3">Item 3 <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="myButton">Add</a></li>
    <li id="item4">Item 4 <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="myButton">Add</a></li>
    <li id="item5">Item 5 <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="myButton">Add</a></li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way using jQuery to can add a new list item below the current one, by click on the corresponding button ?
**Example:** If I click the button for Item 2 I would like the new list item added between Item 2 and Item 3.

I wasn't sure whether I could use `"after"` here and if, how to apply it in this case or if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: I tried append with the ul ID but that always adds the new item at the end of the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#myList').on('click', '.myButton', function () {
    $(this).closest('li').after(createItem());
});

function createItem() {
    //return your HTML, a jQuery object or a DOM element representing
    //the new item to add
}
```

Please note that I did not bother with the `id` number, since I figured you probably don't need the `id` attribute (I guess they were part of your solution to the problem?).

Comment: Perfect - that's what I was looking for. Thanks a lot - will accept as soon as I can.

Comment: @user2571510 Note that you can probably get rid of all those `id` attributes. Glad I could help ;)

Comment: Thanks - yes, will definitely do that as with this solution they are not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is not so hard.

```js
function addAnItem(button){
 var newItem = $('<li>New Item <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="myButton">Add</a></li>');
 newItem.find('.myButton').click(function(){
  addAnItem(this);
 });
 $(button).parent().after(newItem);
}

var list = $('ul').find('.myButton').click(function(){
 addAnItem(this);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <li id="item1">Item 1 <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="myButton">Add</a></li>
 <li id="item2">Item 2 <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="myButton">Add</a></li>
 <li id="item3">Item 3 <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="myButton">Add</a></li>
 <li id="item4">Item 4 <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="myButton">Add</a></li>
 <li id="item5">Item 5 <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="myButton">Add</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Already plenty answers, but just wanted to add my solution. It was a fun excersice for me to figure out how to do this.

```
$('.myButton').click(function() {
    $('<li>New Item</li>').insertAfter($(this).closest('li'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var addedLis=0
$(function(){
    $("#myList").on("click",".myButton",function(){
        addedLis++;
        var _newLI='<li id="addedItem'+addedLis+'">Added Item '+addedLis+' <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="myButton">Add</a></li>'
        $(this).parent().after(_newLI);
    });    
});
```

<kbd>**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/bvhuj98k/)**</kbd>

Answer (score -2):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myList">
    <li id="item1">Item 1 <a onclick='$(this).append("<li>a</li>");' class="myButton">Add</a></li>
    <li id="item2">Item 2 <a onclick='$(this).append("<li>a</li>");' class="myButton">Add</a></li>
    <li id="item3">Item 3<a onclick='$(this).append("<li>a</li>");' class="myButton">Add</a></li>
    <li id="item4">Item 4 <a onclick='$(this).append("<li>a</li>");' class="myButton">Add</a></li>
    <li id="item5">Item 5 <a onclick='$(this).append("<li>a</li>");' class="myButton">Add</a></li>
</ul>
```